# Bind9 REFUSED on same server

Tags: bind, wireguard

I have a local BIND9 DNS server running in a Docker container. In another container I have Wireguard running, which I use to connect to my home network from outside.

The issue I'm running into is that when I select the server IP as a DNS for wireguard, BIND9 keeps refusing the query. If I select my router as DNS (which then forwards to the BIND9 DNS), everything works as expected.

### named.conf.options

```
# BEGIN MANAGED HOMENETWORK BLOCK
acl homenetwork {
  192.168.1.0/24; # home network
  172.17.0.1; # docker host
  192.168.4.0/24; # Wireguard network
  localhost;
  localnets;
};
# END MANAGED HOMENETWORK BLOCK
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    // forwarders {
    //  0.0.0.0;
    // };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    dnssec-validation auto;

# BEGIN MANAGED CACHING BLOCK
recursion yes;
allow-query { homenetwork; };
auth-nxdomain no; # conform to rfc1035
# END MANAGED CACHING BLOCK
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

The IPs in question are 172.17.0.5 for BIND (Docker), 172.17.0.7 for Wireguard (Docker) and 192.168.4.2 (Wireguard client).

### error

```
03-Oct-2023 20:44:52.999 client @0x7ff680007460 172.17.0.1#60081 (gitlab.lan): query 'gitlab.lan/A/IN' denied
```

I tried setting the `acl` to `any;` but that yielded the same error, so it must be something else.
Any hints?

Comment: What's the IP address of the system from where you're making the DNS query?

Comment: Ah, yes, forgot to add that one: 192.168.4.2. I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out I have a `zone` set up as well like so:

```
zone "lan" {
  type master;
  file "/var/lib/bind/lan.hosts";
  allow-query {
    192.168.1.0/24;
  };
};
```

I needed to update that allow-query as well to make it work. My final config now looks like this:

### named.conf.local

```
zone "lan" {
  type master;
  file "/var/lib/bind/lan.hosts";
  allow-query {
    192.168.1.0/24;
    172.17.0.1; 
  };
};
```

### named.conf.options

```
acl homenetwork {
  # home network
  192.168.1.0/24; 
  # docker host
  172.17.0.1; 
  localhost;
  localnets;
};
```